# Slow running SQL query on a large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I am running the below query on a sql server.

```
select * from table1 where added_on in ('2018-09-26','2018-10-02') and uid=309
```

My table contains more than 30 million records. But the above query will result less than 200 records for that it takes 30-40 seconds.

I am having both Clustered and Non-Clustered indexes on the table.

Clustered index for the primary key and Non-clustered index for the added_on (Date field)

Is there any anything still I can use to set on the table to speed up resulting time

Comment: If english has a definition for crore, ok. If not - yeah. English please. And add a query plan please. Also, if you remove in and use 2 normal conditions, does behavior change? WITH query plan. And what hardware?

Comment: 3 crores == 30,000,000 rows?  Anyway, create an index on [uid] and [added_on]: CREATE INDEX IX_Composite ON [table1] ([uid], [added_on]);

Comment: Try changing the order of the `where` clause, get rid of the `*` and create an index on `uid,added_on`.

Comment: @TomTom according to Google, `Crore is a unit in Indian numerical system which is equivalent to 10 million` (thanks OP, I learned a new word today).

Comment: And according to site rules, this is english not indian here.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for correcting my english for others to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an index that covers both fields you are searching on.  Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Composite ON [table1] ([uid], [added_on]);
```

Comment: @MitchWheat also, It might use scan index and not seek.

Comment: your comment is somewhat redundant if the index is not used! :)

Comment: Actually if uid is selective enough - or date is - the other part of the index is mostly irrelevant. Yes, you can throw every possible index at it - does not make it a smart decision. Which is why query plan is good - gives an idea of selectiveness and reasons for decisions, contrary to blindly adding indices.

Comment: All true comments.  I should probably refrain from posting spitball answers.

Comment: A select * could still use that index for lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Im' not sure but try this:

1. create index

   ```
   CREATE INDEX index_name ON table1 (added_on, uid);
   ```
2. This part of your code

   ```
   where added_on in ('2018-09-26','2018-10-02')
   ```

   you write date in ' ' like string type, maybe the database try to convert  it to date type that's waste time.
   try this:

   ```
   where added_on in (to_date('2018-09-26','yyyy-mm-dd'),to_date('2018-10-02','yyyy-mm-dd'))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try not to use `select *` specify the columns you need from this query

You can create and index

```
    CREATE INDEX index_name ON table1 (added_on, uid) include (...what you select...);
```

This way you will have and index seek.

Also maybe try rebuilding primary key and updating statistics. If there is a lot of insert/update operations on the table index my be out of date.

Other than that you could partition your table it can improve performance significantly. Depending on how much data you have, you can for eg. partition by date which in my opinion may really increase performance.

Lastly, check if there are no other heavy jobs on db at the time